# NgRx Selectors not Working in Effects Unit Test

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, angular-test

I am writing unit tests for my NgRx Effects (Resource: https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing). But I have a problem with the `withLatestFrom`. When selecting a slice of my state via an selector (e.g.: `this.store.select( mySelectors.selectId )`), the test throws an error:

```
zone.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at :9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/root-store/my-store/my.selectors.ts:13
    at :9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm5/store.js:504
    at memoized (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm5/store.js:454)
    at defaultStateFn (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm5/store.js:473)
    at :9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm5/store.js:507
    at memoized (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm5/store.js:446)
    at MapSubscriber.project (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm5/store.js:401)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:53)
    at MockState.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/BehaviorSubject.js.BehaviorSubject._subscribe (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/BehaviorSubject.js:22)
```

### But when I am not using my own selector but rather something like this: `this.store.select( state => state.id )`, the test passes.

**Effect**

```
myEffect$ = createEffect( () =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType( myActions.myAction ),
      withLatestFrom(
          // this doesn't work
          this.store.select( mySelectors.selectId ),
          // this works
          // this.store.select( state => state.id ),
      ),
      switchMap( ( [action, id] ) => { /* ... */  } )
  )
);
```

**Selector**

```
export const selectMyState = createFeatureSelector<MyState>( 'feature' );

export const selectId = createSelector(
    selectMyState,
    ( state: MyState ) => state.id
);
```

**Test**

```
describe( 'My Effects', () => {
    let effects: MyEffects;
    let actions: ReplaySubject<any>;
    let store: MockStore<MyState>;

    beforeEach( () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
            imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
            providers: [
                MyEffects,
                provideMockActions( () => actions ),
                provideMockStore( { initialState: fromMy.initialState } ),
                MyService,
            ]
        } );
        TestBed.overrideProvider( MyService, { useValue: new MyMockService() } );

        effects = TestBed.get<MyEffects>( MyEffects );
        store = TestBed.get<Store<RootStoreState.State>>( Store );
    } );

  it( '#myEffect$ should work', () => {
      actions = new ReplaySubject( 1 );
      store.setState( { /* ... */ } );
      actions.next( myActions.myAction() );
      effects.saveEditMy$.subscribe( result => {
          expect( result ).toEqual( myActions.myActionDone( { /* ... */ } ) );
      } );
  } );
} );
```

**MyState Interface**

```
export interface MyState extends EntityState<MyEntity> {
    loading: boolean;
    loaded: boolean;
    error: string;
    buttonStates: string[];
    id: string;
    edit: boolean;
    formData: Partial<MyEntity>;
    isFormValid: boolean;
    isDeletePopupVisible: boolean;
}
```

Comment: your MyState does not have selectedMyId property.

Comment: sorry this was a typo (I have other names in the real code)

Comment: Did you try to override selector (`mySelectors.selectId`) inside `provideMockStore`?

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console if you use the selectId selector in any component?

Comment: @Buczkowski with what would I override it?

Comment: @Chellappan The selector works fine when using it outside tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override selector:

```
provideMockStore({
  initialState: fromMy.initialState,
  selectors: [
    {
      selector: mySelectors.selectId,
      value: 1 // your id
    }
  ]
})
```

Edit 1:

Update selector value in different test cases:

```
store.overrideSelector(mySelectors.selectId, 3); // your id
```

Edit 2:

The case was different here, state in `mySelectors.selectId` was `undefined` because it comes from feature selector which is `feature` so `setState` should be called like this:

```
store.setState({feature:{id: 2}});
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. But I need a different value for different tests. How would I do this?.... this method is also really verbose :(

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any reason why I can't simply use my normal selectors?

Comment: And do I event need to provide a store when I am overriding all selectors anyways?

Comment: @Flo don't really know the reason but I believe it's about mocked store and how its `select` method works.

Comment: @Flo if you won't provide store you get `No provider for Store` error

Comment: Would you rather override all selectors in the test or change the selectors in the effects to `state => state.something`?

Comment: @Flo in my tests I do override all selectors that are in use.

Comment: So you ran into the same issue? Do you `store.setState({})` anyways?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196984/discussion-between-buczkowski-and-flo).

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the Selector with a class.

let store: Store

```
class MockStore {
  select(){}
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 providers: [
   {
     provide: Store,
     useClass: MockStore
   }
 ]
});
store = TestBed.get(Store);
```

And in test suite you can use Spy to give you any slice of store that you want:

```
spyOn(store, 'select').and.returnValue(of(initialState));
```